# Bound on $i$th largest eigenvalue in a large Erdos-Renyi graphs

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, random-matrices, random-graphs

Typical magnitude of $i$th largest eigenvalue of an Erdos-Renyi random graph seems to decay at least exponentially with $i$. Is there an analytic expression for the constant in the exponent, or a nice bound from above in terms of $i$? Any literature pointers appreciated!

[image]

*edit* plot was generated with the following Mathematica command

```
With[{n = 4000},
  Most@Rest@
    Reverse@Sort@
      Abs@Eigenvalues@
        N@Normal@
          AdjacencyMatrix@
           RandomGraph@BernoulliGraphDistribution[n, 0.5]
  ] // ListLogPlot[#, Filling -> Axis, 
   AxesLabel -> {"rank", "log(abs(magnitude))"}, 
   PlotLabel -> "Erdős\[Dash]Rényi"] &
```

Comment: Could you explain what you are plotting?

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke added the command used to make the plot. Basically plotting magnitude of i'th largest eigenvalue of random graph as a function of i, on log scale

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shape is just the CDF of Wigner's semicircle law

[image]

[notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/forum-bernoulli-graphs.nb)

Answered in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4187243/998